How to define variable in useEffect in React?
Below is my variable getting firstname from localStorage:
let = firstname = localStorage.getItem("firstName") ? localStorage.getItem("firstName") : '';

and I am adding above variable below in my iframe:
<IframeWrapper src={`${BASE_URL}`+ formId + `?first_name=${firstname}`} />

Problem is when I deployed this update error says:
WebpackError: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Do I need to define it inside of useEffect or inside of condition typeof window !== "undefined"? I tried to add variable inside useEffect with condition typeof window !== undefined:
useEffect(() => {
    
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      let firstname = localStorage.getItem("firstName") ? localStorage.getItem("firstName") : '';
  
    }
  }, []);

But then it says cannot find name firstname here:
<IframeWrapper src={`${BASE_URL}`+ formId + `?first_name=${firstname}`} />  //here

How I can correctly add first name variable into ?first_name=${firstname}

You can write directly inside the IframeWrapper like this
<IframeWrapper src={`${BASE_URL}`+ formId + `?first_name=${typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("firstName") ? localStorage.getItem("firstName") : ''}`} />

No need of using useEffect

It would be cleaner to define this as a const first and then just past the value to the React component, rather than mixing lots of code in there.
